# How to get Current Tab Item in WPF DevExpress

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, devexpress-wpf

I have a MyList(ID, value1, value2) arranged in tabs (DXTabControl)
Also have a button in my all tabs and I need to pass a parameter (Current Tab Item - actually MyListItem) to another view by clicking a button.

If I have a GridControl, I bind CurrentItem, and what about DXTTabControl?
I only find SelectedItem, SelectedTabItem...

```
<dx:DXTabControl 
x:Name="tabControl" 

ItemHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ItemHeaderTemplate}" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemContentTemplate}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"> 

<dx:DXTabControl.View> 
<dx:TabControlMultiLineView HeaderLocation="Top" /> 
</dx:DXTabControl.View> 

</dx:DXTabControl>
```

Comment: Please show us more code. (DataTemplate for MyList, Location of the button you wrote about). Without knowing this, we can only guess. My guess would be a CommandParameter Binding without ANY path. In default approches, this would be often an item of MyList. But really, this just depends on your way to create the tab content...

Comment: That's what I needed CommandParameter Binding without ANY path! Thanks a lot You can place Your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @Songaila I too have the same structure but I am not able to find the selectedTab. It returns null to me. I am also using ItemHeaderTemplate. Can you help?